# How do I store a value from a DataFrame in a new variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I store the value of a particular location from a Dataframe into separate, non-dataframe variable?

I tried the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX.txt', sep='\t', header=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

check-sum = (df.iloc[0,0])
```

But received a Syntax Error: 'can't assign to operator'.

I expected check-sum = 50.23 (integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the **variable name (check-sum)**. You can't have hyphen in variable name as it is the *subtraction* operator. Once you remove the hyphen e.g. check_sum = (df.iloc[0,0]), You'll see the expected result.

Comment: ROFL - duh. Thanks!